# How to insert records from a mysql query to a wxPython listCtrl widget?

Tags: mysql, wxpython, listctrl

I have a simple code that needs to output correctly the rows I'd like to pull out from a mysql query. Please see my code below. Don't know what really is wrong. I've tried to search on the Net but no luck.

```
sql="""SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY fname ASC LIMIT 5"""        
    cr.execute(sql)
    rows = cr.fetchall()

    self.list=wx.ListCtrl(panel,pos=(20,100),size=(355,130),
                          style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.SUNKEN_BORDER|wx.LC_HRULES|wx.LC_VRULES)

    self.list.InsertColumn(0, 'Name')
    self.list.InsertColumn(1, 'Email')
    self.list.InsertColumn(2, 'Contact Number', width=150)

    self.list.SetColumnWidth(0, 100)
    self.list.SetColumnWidth(1, 200)
    self.list.SetColumnWidth(2, 100)

    n=0
    for r in rows:
        self.list.InsertStringItem()(n, r[0])
        self.list.SetStringItem(n, 1, r[1])
        self.list.InsertItem(n, 2, r[2])
        n+=1
```

I'm getting the error "return *controls*.ListCtrl_InsertStringItem(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: String or Unicode type required". Help from anyone is very much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You have excessive `)(` in your code here `self.list.InsertStringItem()(n, r[0])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the for loop, you need to just use the SetStringItem command for every column except the first one. So instead of "self.list.InsertItem(n, 2, r[2])" it should be self.list.SetStringItem (n, 2, r[2])

Personally, I would use ObjectListView instead of ListCtrl. I wrote up a nice tutorial on using it with SQLAlchemy and SQLite here:

http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/11/10/wxpython-and-sqlalchemy-an-intro-to-mvc-and-crud/

That might be helpful to you too.